# perl lazy match external file with regular expression

Tags: perl

I have an `index.html` file that contains a string like:

`vendor.adsf34.bundle.js blah blah  inline.1r34afer.bundle.js`

I've built the following code (mac, iterm2):

```
perl -i -pe 's/vendor\..+?\.js/vendor.js/g;' index.html
perl -i -pe 's/inline\..+?\.js/inline.js/g;' index.html
```

However I end up with:

`vendor.js`

ie, it seems to be greedy matching where I need it to be lazy.

What I'm trying to do is shorten the js names, eg as follows:

`vendor.js blah blah inline.js`

Be great to get some pointers!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: On 2nd thought, yes, your example works for me too. Lazy match operators are inefficient though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

- look for a fixed start string (`vendor.` or `inline.`) <sup>1</sup>
- look for one-or-more non-space characters
- look for a fixed end string (`.js`)
- replace it with <sup>1</sup> + `.js`

```
$ echo "vendor.adsf34.bundle.js blah blah  inline.1r34afer.bundle.js" | perl -pe 's/(vendor|inline)\.\S+\.js/\1.js/g'
vendor.js blah blah  inline.js
```